# L2 regularization keep increasing during training

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am finetuning InceptionResnetV2 on TensorFlow. When training, the regularization loss keep linearly increasing and even much larger than cross entropy loss in the later stage of training. I have checked the training procedure, and make sure I am optimizing the cross entropy loss and L2 loss combined.

Is there anyone explain this weird thing a little bit? Any feedback is appreciated.

Here is the code and some TensorBoard plots.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import tf_logging as logging
from inception_resnet_v2 import inception_resnet_v2, inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope
import os
import time
from preprocessing import aug_parallel_v2
import numpy as np

slim = tf.contrib.slim

# total training data number
sample_num = 625020

data_path = 'iNaturalist_train.tfrecords'

# State where your log file is at. If it doesn't exist, create it.
log_dir = './log_v5'
# tensorboard visualization path
filewriter_path = './filewriter_v5_Logits'

# State where your checkpoint file is
checkpoint_file = './inception_resnet_v2_2016_08_30.ckpt'
checkpoint_save_addr = './log_v5/fine-tuning_v5.ckpt'
# State the image size you're resizing your images to. We will use the default inception size of 299.
image_size = 299

# State the number of classes to predict:
num_classes = 8142

# ================= TRAINING INFORMATION ==================
# State the number of epochs to train
num_epochs = 5

# State your batch size
batch_size = 60

# Learning rate information and configuration
initial_learning_rate = 0.0005
learning_rate_decay_factor = 0.8
num_epochs_before_decay = 2

# put weight on different classes inversely proportional
# to total number of their image samples
label_count = np.loadtxt('label_count.txt', dtype=int)
inverse = lambda t: 1 / t
vfunc = np.vectorize(inverse)
multiplier = vfunc(label_count)
multiplier /= np.mean(multiplier)

def run():

    if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
        os.mkdir(log_dir)

    feature = {'train/height': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'train/width': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'train/image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
               'train/label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'train/sup_label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
               'train/aug_level': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)}

    # create a list of file names
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([data_path], num_epochs=None)
    print(filename_queue)

    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, tfrecord_serialized = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(tfrecord_serialized, features=feature)

    # Convert the image data from string back to the numbers
    height = tf.cast(features['train/height'], tf.int64)
    width = tf.cast(features['train/width'], tf.int64)

    # change this line for your TFrecord version
    tf_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(features['train/image'])

    tf_label = tf.cast(features['train/label'], tf.int32)
    aug_level = tf.cast(features['train/aug_level'], tf.int32)
    # tf_sup_label = tf.cast(features['train/sup_label'], tf.int64)

    tf_image = tf.reshape(tf_image, tf.stack([height, width, 3]))
    tf_label = tf.reshape(tf_label, [1])
    aug_level = tf.reshape(aug_level, [1])

    resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(images=tf_image, size=tf.constant([400, 400]), method=2)
    resized_image = tf.cast(resized_image, tf.uint8)
    tf_images, tf_labels, tf_aug = tf.train.shuffle_batch([resized_image, tf_label, aug_level], batch_size=batch_size,
                                                      capacity=2048, num_threads=16, allow_smaller_final_batch=False,
                                                      min_after_dequeue=256)


    tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)  # Set the verbosity to INFO level

    IMAGE_HEIGHT = 299
    IMAGE_WIDTH = 299

    images = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 299, 299, 3])
    labels = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=[None, 1])
    weighted_level = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 1])

    # Know the number steps to take before decaying the learning rate and batches per epoch
    num_batches_per_epoch = int(sample_num / batch_size)
    num_steps_per_epoch = num_batches_per_epoch  # Because one step is one batch processed
    decay_steps = int(num_epochs_before_decay * num_steps_per_epoch)

    # Create the model inference
    with slim.arg_scope(inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope()):
        logits, end_points = inception_resnet_v2(images, num_classes=num_classes, is_training=True)

    # Define the scopes that you want to exclude for restoration
    exclude = ['InceptionResnetV2/Logits', 'InceptionResnetV2/AuxLogits']
    variables_to_restore = slim.get_variables_to_restore(exclude=exclude)

    print("label test")
    print(labels)
    print(logits)

    # Perform one-hot-encoding of the labels (Try one-hot-encoding within the load_batch function!)
    one_hot_labels = tf.squeeze(tf.one_hot(labels, num_classes), [1])

    print(one_hot_labels)
    print(logits)

    weighted_onehot = tf.multiply(one_hot_labels, weighted_level)

    # Performs the equivalent to tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits but enhanced with checks
    digits_loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=weighted_onehot, logits=logits)

    reg_loss = tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()

    total_loss = digits_loss + reg_loss

    # Define your exponentially decaying learning rate
    lr = tf.train.exponential_decay(
        learning_rate=initial_learning_rate,
        global_step=global_step,
        decay_steps=decay_steps,
        decay_rate=learning_rate_decay_factor,
        staircase=True)

    # train_vars = []
    # Now we can define the optimizer that takes on the learning rate
    train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                                          "InceptionResnetV2/Logits")

    # RMSProp or Adam

    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr)

    # Create the train_op.
    train_op = slim.learning.create_train_op(total_loss, optimizer, variables_to_train=train_vars)

    predictions = tf.argmax(end_points['Predictions'], 1)
    probabilities = end_points['Predictions']
    accuracy, accuracy_update = tf.metrics.accuracy(predictions, labels)
    metrics_op = tf.group(accuracy_update, probabilities)

    tf.summary.scalar('losses/Reg_Loss', reg_loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('losses/Digit_Loss', digits_loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('losses/Total_Loss', total_loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('accuracy', accuracy)
    tf.summary.scalar('learning_rate', lr)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(filewriter_path)
    writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())

    my_summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

    def train_step(sess, train_op, global_step, imgs, lbls, weight):
        '''
        Simply runs a session for the three arguments provided and gives a logging on the time elapsed
        for each global step
        '''
        # Check the time for each sess run
        start_time = time.time()

        total_loss, global_step_count, _ = sess.run([train_op, global_step, metrics_op],
                                                    feed_dict={images: imgs, labels: lbls, weighted_level: weight})

        time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time

        # Run the logging to print some results
        logging.info('global step %s: digit_loss: %.4f (%.2f sec/step)',
                     global_step_count, total_loss, time_elapsed)

        return total_loss, global_step_count

    saver_pretrain = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
    saver_train = tf.train.Saver(train_vars)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(init_op)

        # Create a coordinator and run all QueueRunner objects
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        saver_pretrain.restore(sess, checkpoint_file)

        start_time = time.time()

        for step in range(int(num_steps_per_epoch * num_epochs)):

            imgs, lbls, augs = sess.run([tf_images, tf_labels, tf_aug])

            imgs, lbls = aug_parallel_v2(imgs, lbls, augs)

            imgs = imgs[:, 50:349, 50:349, :]

            imgs = 2*(imgs.astype(np.float32)) - 1

            lbls = lbls.astype(np.int32)

            weight = multiplier[lbls]

            weight = np.array(weight).reshape((batch_size, 1))

            # print(imgs[0, 0:10, 0:10, 0:2])

            if step % num_batches_per_epoch == 0:
                logging.info('Epoch %s/%s', step / num_batches_per_epoch + 1, num_epochs)

                learning_rate_value, accuracy_value = sess.run([lr, accuracy],
                                                feed_dict={images: imgs, labels: lbls, weighted_level: weight})

                logging.info('Current Learning Rate: %s', learning_rate_value)
                logging.info('Current Streaming Accuracy: %s', accuracy_value)

                # optionally, print your logits and predictions for a sanity check that things are going fine.
                logits_value, probabilities_value, predictions_value, labels_value = sess.run(
                    [logits, probabilities, predictions, labels],
                    feed_dict={images: imgs, labels: lbls, weighted_level: weight})

                print('logits: \n', logits_value)

                print('Probabilities: \n', probabilities_value)

                print('predictions: \n', predictions_value)

                print('Labels:\n:', labels_value)

            # Log the summaries every 10 step.
            if step % 20 == 0:

                loss, global_step_count = train_step(sess, train_op, global_step, imgs, lbls, weight)

                summaries = sess.run(my_summary_op, feed_dict={images: imgs, labels: lbls, weighted_level: weight})

                writer.add_summary(summaries, global_step_count)
                # sess.summary_computed(sess, summaries)

            # If not, simply run the training step

            else:
                loss, _ = train_step(sess, train_op, global_step, imgs, lbls, weight)

            if step % 2000 == 0:

                logging.info('Saving model to disk now.')
                saver_train.save(sess, checkpoint_save_addr, global_step=global_step)

            print('one batch time: ', time.time() - start_time)

            start_time = time.time()

        # We log the final training loss and accuracy
        logging.info('Final Loss: %s', loss)
        logging.info('Final Accuracy: %s', sess.run(accuracy))

        # Once all the training has been done, save the log files and checkpoint model
        logging.info('Finished training! Saving model to disk now.')
        saver_train.save(sess, checkpoint_save_addr, global_step=global_step)

        # Stop the threads
        coord.request_stop()

        # Wait for threads to stop
        coord.join(threads)
        sess.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I am new here, and don't have enough reputation to post images.
Here are two links for the accuracy plot and losses plot. You can easily tell the regularization loss is in a dominant position.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult question to answer. I can give some pointers though.

In general, when you try to minimize `digits_loss`, that is to fit your model to your data, you will slowly change the weights in your layers. To counter potential overfitting, a L2 regularization loss (the sum of the squares of all weights, `reg_loss` in your code) is generally added to the overall loss (`total_loss` in your code.) These two forces generally act against each other and if the balance is right, you train a good model.

In your case you're taking a network (`resnet_v2`) that was developed for 1,001 classes and try to predict 8,142 classes. No problem with that per se, but you're upsetting the balance. So I believe you need to override the default weight decay of 0.00004 for resnet v2 to some higher value, in this line (note only 3 zeros in the decimals for a 10x increase):

```
with slim.arg_scope( inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope( weight_decay = 0.0004 ) ):
```

A higher `weight_decay` parameter will force the L2 loss to decrease faster. The problem is that this number is just a guess, I have no idea what an ideal value would be. You need to experiment with multiple values and figure it out.

Comment: I have tried your method to use a larger weight_decay. The reg_loss goes up very quickly and gradually and slowly decreases. But the weight decay might be too large. The performance(accuracy) of my model stays in a very low level. Do you have any idea about the reason that the reg loss always goes up in training?

Comment: So basically it _has_ to go up initially as your model starts to take shape in the first few hundred steps after initialization. Some weights grow larger, some decay, but instead of the original normal distribution now you have a very arbitrary distribution of weights, as it should be. So it's very normal for it to increase initially. Unfortunately, you have to experiment to find out which `weight_decay` value gives you the best results. It's called _hyperparameter exploration_. If you have more hardware at your disposal, you can run several copies simultaneously with different values.

Comment: I understand the L2 loss would increase if we train from scratch. But I am finetuning the InceptionResnetV2, whose variables would be reasonable already. I think the L2 loss should not increase for several thousand iterations. And the most weird thing is the digit_loss is also increasing in the beginning. Maybe there is a bug in my code...

Comment: You're training the last layer from scratch. Or maybe your learning rate is too high. But yes, it's also possible you have a bug of some other nature. Welcome to deep learning... :)

Comment: Hahaha  Thank you, Sir! I have tried several weight decay values, also tried to finetuning all variables together, but cannot get rid of the problem. The digit_loss increasing at first and gradually decrease; while the reg_loss decrease and then increase linearly with time. The linearity is so weird and annoying. It totally block the optimization for digit_loss. For more than 20, 000 iterations, the reg_loss is three times larger than digit_loss....

Comment: Yeah, if it increases forever linearly, then you most probably have some kind of a bug and it's not just hyperparameter setting. One idea: `exclude = ['InceptionResnetV2/Logits', 'InceptionResnetV2/AuxLogits']` excludes the aux head as well, but `train_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, "InceptionResnetV2/Logits")` excludes them, but both training and regularization losses probably still include the auxiliary head. Just a thought.

Comment: When I am finetuning the whole network, including aux_loss, this thing still won't change. The reg_loss increases endlessly with an optimizer on it. If it keep decreasing, I believe it can be the reason you proposed about Aux head. But now, TensorFlow really get me confused.

Comment: Next idea, you're weighting the one_hot labels like `weighted_onehot = tf.multiply(one_hot_labels, weighted_level)`. This is highly unusual, you don't normally change the 0-1 nature of one hot labels. If you want to weight the _loss_ based on class prevalence, then you normally use the `loss_weight` parameter of the loss function, so something like `tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=one_hot_labels, logits=logits, weights = weighted_level)` This bug can potentially explain the L2 explosion: it tries to chase a larger than 1 value. --Sorry, got to go to sleep now, it's 3:30AM here.

Comment: Good Night! Never heard about this loss_weight term, definitely gonna try it soon. But I have tried to remove the label weight. It didn't work neither. Still linear increasing reg_loss. I will divide my model into parts and test them one by one. I will report my result here. Also, if you have any ideas, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: It might not be that either then. Well the way I usually do this  it is starting at a known good place. So start with _inception_resnet_v2_ and implement your own network changing the code piece by piece, and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: Same idea. It might be a long Debug process. Good luck to me. Thank you for your patient followup! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure. Once you find the bug, you could leave a comment, I'm kind of curious! :) Also if you thought my thoughts were useful for you, even though the code is not fixed (so don't accept the answer), it would be customary to upvote my answer and/or the useful comments.

Comment: Hey, I finally figure out this thing. Just change the tf.get_regularization_loss() to an older form tf.reduce_sum(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.REGULARIZATION_LOSSES)). This perfectly solved my problem. Although the reg_loss still increase a little bit at the very beginning, but it is totally understandable. After a week's training, I get almost 80% top3 accuracy. Not bad!

Comment: Ok that means [`tf.losses.get_regularization_loss()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/get_regularization_loss) has a problem. That might be useful for other people, I'll incorporate that into my answer. What Tensorflow version do you have?

Comment: I think it’s 1.6. For the function of tf.get_regularization_loss,   We can read the source code to discover its differences with GraghKey approach.